# How to tell a wlan card supports RFMON mode

Tags: wireless

Can someone please tell me how to check if a wlan card supports promiscuous mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFMON support depends on the chipset used in the adapter. Research the wlan card, find out what chipset it uses, and then find out if the chipset can operate in RFMON mode with the right driver.

[This](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers) website is an excellent resource for just that.

Answer (score 3):

To check if your wireless card supports monitor mode, you can use `iw list`.

Run in a terminal:

`iw list`

Output:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
```

In `Supported interface modes`, if you find `monitor` to be present then that means that your wireless card supports monitor mode.